# Square API for Android

Tags: square-connect

I have built an android app that allows customers to order custom made sandwiches through a tablet. I want to use Square to accept credit card payment once they are done but I want it to me implemented through my app. When I search around I find a lot of mix thoughts on whether this is possible or not. The documentation says "Approved developers can use the Square Register API to communicate with Square Register from their iOS app", however when I email and explain my situation, the square support say that it is possible to use square connect on Android and I don't need to be approved when it is only a single tablet.

Now I was wondering if anyone has done something similar and would be willing to share their experience. I know that paypal for example provides android SDK and even have an example app on Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible for Android apps (other than Square Register) to process card payments with Square. The [Register API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#register-api-overview) is currently available only to approved iOS applications.

Comment: Turns out there was a misunderstanding on the email. They also go back to me with the same information. Thank you